# Can a user currently login an External application A be able to directly access application B with CAS as SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

I am new to CAS and SSO.
Currently we have an application, say App1, with CAS implementation for login. As per the new requirements an User who is already login to another application, say App2, should be able to access App1 through App2 via link with out login. Does CAS allow this kind of integration?

User ---------> External App2 ----------> CAS ===== App1

Your help is much appreciated.

We are using CAS 3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That is what SSO means. You login once, you login everywhere.

Comment: Hi Misagh, Thanks for your answer, I have a question here. With reference to my question, please note that App2 is an external application, which has its own login process. However the user id will be the same. Can a user still access App1 which is behind an external CAS system. Please advise.

Comment: If you wish for both apps to recognize CAS authentication, then they need to both be integrated with CAS using some sort of CAS client. Doesn't matter if they are internal and/or external. They MUST support CAS. Once they do, you can link to one from the other.

There is no magic here. The app must recognize CAS, or you'd have to build custom plugins for it to do so.

Comment: Also note that CAS 3.x is dead.